# Windows Server Backup and Microsoft Azure Backup

Tags: azure, backup

Since Azure agent doesn't support full VM image backups directly through the portal (without shutting down the VM first), I wanted to schedule a regular bare metal backup of my Azure VMs using Windows Server Backup together with the Azure Backup agent.

The challenge is to find a temporary place to store the files created by WSB while Azure Backup agent transfers them to the Azure backup store. I first thought the VM temporary disk ( D:\ ) would be suitable, but it turns out that on some VMs the temp disk is smaller than the OS disk and would thus not have enough space.

An option is of course to attach one extra 127 GB disk to each VM and use that as a destination volume for WSB backups and use Azure backup agent to backup that volume, but this would incur significant extra storage charges, since you would pay for both the extra disks storage and the backup storage.

The best thing would of course be if the functionality of Azure backup agent was built into Windows Server backup, but this is not the case, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As of now if you want to schedule a regular bare metal backup of Azure VMs, you can use the Temporary drive to store the files created by WSB if the OS disk size is less than Temporary drive(D:). Else, you have to attach a additional Data disk for backup purpose.

I agree it will incur extra charge for using the storage disk. But there is no work around for it now.

You may provide your requirement as Feedback to Azure Backup/Windows Server backup team through below link:

http://feedback.azure.com/forums/258995-azure-backup-and-scdpm